# IE clear float dont work (for footer) and disapear

Tags: internet-explorer

I have that [page](http://ldetek.com/LDP1000-tab2.php), in FF it's fine, and in ff PC too, but again in ie the footer disapear for no reason... can you help ?

Comment: I don't think it's going to solve your problem, but why is `#tab_container` set to float: left?

Comment: i remove float as suggested, no luck !....

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Page displays fine in IE8 (+ compatibility mode) for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is persisten in IE6, reading around i got some information from : [Matthew James Taylor](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) talking on is page about KEEPING footer to the bottom.... wich lead to FIX the bu... thanks anyway for trying!